# Random applications contain totally white screen

Tags: windows-10, white-screen

I unfortunately need to have Windows on my desktop. I've had white applications before, but now I need it really working.

Some applications ([like windows adk installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeN0N.png)) display a totally white screen, but I am able to interact with all buttons inside the window. How can I get it fixed?

Comment: There is not enough information for an answer, but an educated guess is that Windows 10 has not been completely installed.

Comment: The ADK installer runs using .NET WPF. Try disabling Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0 service and rename the file C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT. WPF also requires DirectX, so it may be worth trying to reinstall that as well or maybe even your graphics drivers. Are there any errors in the event log?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it's probably Windows update, tough I do my best to let it do it's thing...

Comment: @mt025 I did everything besides DirectX reinstallation, since I have no idea how to do that. Nothing found in event log by custom view, but I got an error 13 (query is too long), when selecting Applications and Services/Microsoft/Windows. I refuse to select all of the folders in there 1 by 1. Still get the problem.

Answer (score 1):

refer to the following steps.

step 1:   run sfc.exe

run the following command:
**DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth**
**sfc /scannow**

And if you get any message, please refer to the link to repair.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

step 2: Update or re-install graphic driver

**Win+X** -> **Device Manager** -> **find your graphic cards** -> **expand it** -> **right click it** -> **select Update driver.(or re-install)**

step 3: install the windows update or hotfix

Press the **Win+I** keyboard shortcut.
From **System Settings** click on **Update & Security**
From the **Windows Update**, check for update and install them.

Comment: I have already tried those and they don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue on Windows 10 in Virtual machine (vmware SVGA 3D graphic driver) and blank screen for program "Avira Free Security". Problem appeared suddenly and Avira was working before.

Only solution (or workaround) I found is setting "High Crontrast" in Windows Settings. This way I can see the application window!